# How to create MS Access 2010 Add-in in MS Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ribbon-control

please can you help me how to create MS Access 2010 Add-in in MS Visual Studio 2010?

In VS 2010 Profesional, there are only teplates for creating Add-in for Excel, Word, but not for Access.

Can I somewhere download template for MS Access Add-in project?

Comment: I don't understand, why this question was closed??? I just need to know why in VS 2010 there is project template for Excel add-in and no for Access add-in. And where can I get Access add-in template for VS 2010.

Comment: Finally I found solution here: http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2010/09/27/office-access-2010-addins/